# How to process a file in Perl - handling variables from Bash: disappearing "." character

Tags: perl, bash, unix-timestamp

I need to find the age of a file in seconds but when I give my Perl line:

```
perl -e ' my @st=stat("$name"); print time -  $st[9];'
```

a variable from Bash with "." in the filename, it won't find the file and prints the systime instead. Otherwise, if I create a file with a name such "something", it works perfectly well.

I tried escaping the character with \ but that does not work. I really do not know Perl and I don't know how to figure this out.

Thanks for the help!

(Please, do not suggest any BASH only workarounds, lot of stuff here is old, truncated...)

**EDIT:** I found a workaround but I can't post an answer to my own question since I am a newbie, so here it is:

So I finally found a workaround.

You export the variable in Bash:

```
export name=".file.txt"
```

and then call it from the Perl like this: `$ENV{name}`

and it works just fine.

**EDIT 2:**

The export idea was just a temporary solution. Better one is using single quotes as perreal suggested.

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in bash in single quotes. Perl's variable $name is unset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the shell variable out of the single quotes:

```
perl -e ' my @st=stat("'"$name"'"); print time - $st[9];'
```

or pass it through arguments:

```
perl -se 'my @st=stat("$name"); print time - $st[9];' -- -name="$name"
```

Comment: The export I suggested isn't a good solution. Thank you for your help. I'm now using the single quotes idea.